# Can I load an abstract class at runtime in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, load, abstract-class

I'm making a card game where I assign random effects to cards, so I need to load the effect's code at runtime with just the class name.

I don't know if my abstract class and child are done properly, and I also don't exactly know how to get the class needed from a path.
I know Resouces.Load won't work but I'll leave it there to convey what I wanna do more easily.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

 public Effect effect;

 ...

 effect = Resources.Load<Effect>("Card/Effects/" + c.cardActual.effect1);

                if (effect.Execution())
                {
                    StartCoroutine(TargetAndCastSpell(c,p));
                }
```

This is the code for my abstract class

```
    public abstract class Effect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string targetType;
    public List<int> availableTargets;
    public int effectTier;
    public PlayerHolder playerTarget;
    public CardPhysicalInstance minionTarget;
    public PlayerHolder caster;
    public void EffectX(PlayerHolder PlayerTarget, CardPhysicalInstance MinionTarget)
    {
    }
    public bool Execution()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And lastly the child I want to load in runtime

```
 class Spark : Effect
{
    string targetType = "any";
    //Deal 1 damage to any target

    public bool Execution ()
    {
        bool canTarget = false;
        caster = GameManager.singleton.currentPlayer;
        availableTargets = SpellHelper.AvailableTargets();
        if (targetType == "any") //Placeholder check
        {
            canTarget = true;
            caster.playerState = GameManager.PlayerState.targeting;
        }


        return canTarget;

    }
```

...

Any help is deeply appreciated, thanks and sorry about my clear lack of understanding of abstract classes.

Comment: "Load" is not a term commonly used. Do you mean "create a instance of the type"? Or "dynamic creation of types" at runtime? | The later route is generally a XY Problem, so it would help if you told us *why* you think that is the way to go. What problem you tried to solve.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't mention this was in Unity,  so I'm used to loading most stuff on runtime through Resources.Load or AddComponent.

I'm not sure about what's the best way to go here, I just suggested what came to mind thus far, but again might be totally wrong.

Comment: Unity loves the Factory Pattern. So you are propably creating a instance with somebody elses code - like `Load ` and `AddComponent`.

Comment: Noted. Either way, my problem is that I need a piece of code capable of getting the correct file and executing the "Execution" function you see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, I think Overriding is the Droid you are looking for. With Polymorphy there is two ways different Implementations can be resolved.

- hiding is possibly by default. However, it is also pretty much useless. It is one of those things we thought we need and now everyone adds it to their OOP language. But aside from not using hiding when I *wanted* to overwrite, I have never had any use for it.
- Overriding is the important thing. However, overriding has to be allowed for a function in the base class that first added it.

In Effect:

```
//Stil work how it does, but now can be overridden
public virtual bool Execution()
{
    return false;
}
```

In Spark:

```
//We are actually overriding - not just hiding - Effect.Execution() here
public override bool Execution ()
{
    bool canTarget = false;
    caster = GameManager.singleton.currentPlayer;
    availableTargets = SpellHelper.AvailableTargets();
    if (targetType == "any") //Placeholder check
    {
        canTarget = true;
        caster.playerState = GameManager.PlayerState.targeting;
    }


    return canTarget;

}
```

You can assign a Spark to a Effect variable, call `Execution()` and Polymorphy will deal with calling the version of Spark.

Add anotehr Effect sub-class? As long as it also overrides `Execution()` it works the same.

The Effect version could be empty/turned abstract. Or be kept as a default version for all subclasses.

With hiding you would have to cast it back to Spark to get access to it's variant of the Method. Wich is just extra work with no apparent advantage.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I knew something was missing there for the child to properly -override- the function.

Now the thing is I don't know how to assign that spark to that effect variable. I want to do it based on the " c.cardActual.effect1" parameter noted above (In this case a string containing the target class name "Spark"), since the idea is having a couple hundred of different effects.

Comment: @Fullen You assign a Spark instance ot a effect variable, the way you would assing a (purely theoretical) Effect instance. `Effect someEffect = new Spark();`. Being the type that all child types can fit, is what a base class is there for.

Comment: Right but I have a bunch of effects and I don't know how to instantiate that effect at runtime. While running I can get any of them so I need some code that can take just the name of the needed child and load that code into my `someEffect` variable.
Sorry if I'm missing something here and thanks for your time-

Comment: Well, I finally got it running as intended. I needed to create an instance but I was struggling with the type name, turns out I wasn't including the namespace before the actual name. 
`effect = (Effect)System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("SA.Spark"));`

This is the code, although the final code won't be hardcoded like that, obviously.

Comment: @Fullen Fun fact: `MonoBehaviour` is a dedicated base class. It could even be abstract, but I do not know for sure. Functions like `Resources.Load<T>()` will put instances into a global `List<MonoBehaviour>`. That functions like `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll()` will look in that list. I would guess the hidden Game Loop will also call some of those Update functions as appropirate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_programming#Game_structure